# Issue with getting/setting iframe contents

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've read here that iframe has limitations when it comes to cross-domain content. But does that also mean that loading another file from the same domain is not allowed? I've been unsuccessfully trying out this code, but it only works if the iframe source is the same file, ie. index.html:

*index.html*

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- re-loading itself works -->
    <!-- iframe id="myFrame" width="640" height="480" src="index.html"></iframe-->

    <iframe id="myFrame" width="640" height="480" src="anotherFile.html"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function()
      {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
          iframeWin = document.getElementById("myFrame");
          iframeWin.height = iframeWin.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + "px";
        }, 1000);
      }
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Due to the external file requirement, I'm unable to post to jsFiddle.

**EDIT: The contents of *anotherFile.html*:**

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<br> 
            of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> 
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard<br>
            dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an...</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What the error are you getting?

Comment: The code just breaks. If I place an *alert()* within *setTimeout()* function, it doesn't get executed. Perhaps an undefined value error. It's easily testable; simply cut, paste, save as *index.html*, and run. If the source is changed back to *index.html* it works.

Comment: Are you sure your code in `anotherFile.html` is correct?

Comment: It's just a simple test file with some paragraph text.

Answer (score 2):

You try this by the onload event of iframe instead of setTimeOut

```
 <iframe id="myFrame" width="640" height="480" src="response.html"  onload="myFunction()"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction(){
      iframeWin = document.getElementById("myFrame");
      iframeWin.height = iframeWin.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + "px";
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Still the same. To test it, I inserted an *alert()* into the function, but it only executes if the second line *iframeWin.height = ...* is commented out.

Comment: It's working fine in my side with alert also. Before the alert the height of the iframe is larger as the default value of the iframe is larger and then after the alert it's reducing the height of the iframe.

Comment: I think you might have issue with the permission of the external file. You can check it in the browser console.

Comment: Indra, you seem to be right about the permissions; Chrome throws this error: **Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.** How would I overcome this?

Comment: But I didn't got the issue in my machine. It is the issue with browser security.Otherwise the code is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Why is the error triggered when both files are technically in the same domain *ie. residing on my local drive* ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Apparently the problem is with a security setting in Google Chrome:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121406
- http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

The feature works on FireFox and MSIE, and also on Chrome if run from a web server.